# Difference between copying a list to another with or without 'new' - JAVA

Tags: java, list, copy, clone

1) What is the difference between

```
for (MyObject myObject : sessionBean.firstList()) {
    secondList.add(new MyObject(myObject.getSeverity(), myObject.getSummary(), myObject.getDetail()));
}
```

and

```
for (MyObject myObject : sessionBean.firstList()) {
    secondList.add(facesMessage);
}
```

considering that i later want to clear sessionBean.firstList but want to retain the values in secondList.

2) Is there a more readable way of doing it in java 8?

Comment: What would happened if you modified one or more of the objects in the `secondList`?  This would basically answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in single statement in a readable way:

```
   secondList.addAll(sessionBean.firstList())
```

When you use new you will allocate additional memory, otherwise you are mapping the reference of the existing objects. Even if you want to clear the sessionBean.firstList later point of time, if you have a valid reference for that objects in another collection,it will not be collected by garbage collector. So I could not see any valid scenario to compel to use the new operator.

Comment: How does that answer the question?

Comment: @Steephen Does this mean that the second one is a deep copy?

Comment: @overflow yes it is a deep copy. But for your purpose even first one is even enough.

Answer (score 0):

1) The difference is that in the first case the `secondList` will contain references to new objects with same fields as in the `firstList`. And in the second case `secondList` will contain references to the **same** objects as in the `firstList`. So if you modify one of your `firstList` items, the corresponding item in the `secondList` will be modified too.

2) You can use the following example to create a list with copies:

```
List<MyObject> secondList = sessionBean.firstList()
    .stream()
    .map(first -> new MyObject(first.getSeverity(), first.getSummary(), first.getDetail()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you implement a `clone` method in your `MyObject` class

```
public MyObject clone() {
    return new MyObject(severity, summary, detail);
}
```

you can simply write:

```
List<MyObject> secondList = sessionBean.firstList()
     .stream()
     .map(MyObject::clone)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or if you just want to copy references, use

```
secondList.addAll(sessionBean.firstList())
```